# Base 64 Encoding a SHA-1 Hash in the Bash Shell

Tags: bash, utf-8, base64, sha

I have a Python command that generates the URL-safe base-64 encoding of the SHA-1 hash of a string:

```
>>> import base64
>>> import sha
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64encode((sha.new("abc").digest()))
'qZk-NkcGgWq6PiVxeFDCbJzQ2J0='
```

I want to do the same thing in the bash shell, but I'm running into problems:

```
me:~$ echo -n "abc" | sha1sum | sed 's/ .*//' 
a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d
me:~$ echo -n "abc" | sha1sum | sed 's/ .*//' | base64
YTk5OTNlMzY0NzA2ODE2YWJhM2UyNTcxNzg1MGMyNmM5Y2QwZDg5ZAo=
```

I suspect that this is because of the way that sha1sum prints out (in hex format). I think base64 is reading 40 bytes, but it really should only be reading 20. I've tried piping it through iconv, but no success there:

```
me:~$ echo -n "abc" | sha1sum | sed 's/ .*//' 
a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d
me:~$ echo -n "abc" | sha1sum | sed 's/ .*//' | base64
YTk5OTNlMzY0NzA2ODE2YWJhM2UyNTcxNzg1MGMyNmM5Y2QwZDg5ZAo=
```

What should I be doing here to get the output I'm expecting?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Would it not be simpler to print the SHA1 in hex from Python? That is the almost universal human-readable representation for this particular data type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

digest() is not the same as hexdigest()

```
base64.urlsafe_b64encode((sha.new("abc").hexdigest()))
'YTk5OTNlMzY0NzA2ODE2YWJhM2UyNTcxNzg1MGMyNmM5Y2QwZDg5ZA=='
```

Docstring for digest:

```
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
Base Class: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:<built-in method digest of _hashlib.HASH object at 0x1c88940>
Namespace:  Interactive
Docstring:  Return the digest value as a **string of binary data**.
```

**EDIT:** Try:

```
echo -n "abc"| openssl sha1 -binary | base64
qZk+NkcGgWq6PiVxeFDCbJzQ2J0=
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm trying to get the Bash command output to match the Python output; not the other way around. The method used in my Python command is out of my control.

Comment: Just saw the edit. Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: That's because I used urlsafe_b64encode() instead of just b64encode() in the Python command. All that does is replace '+' characters with '-', and '/' characters with '_'.